# Java: Null pointer when trying to set app icon

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, icons

I'm trying to set an icon for my Java app, with the image being in assets/images.

Setting it as so:

```
java.net.URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("assets/images/ravens.jpg");
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = kit.createImage(url);
frame.setIconImage(img);
```

Error I'm receiving:

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:125)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How did you compile and run your app?

Comment: Is `assets` inside your build path?

Comment: Where does the `assest` directory reside?

Comment: Simply under the parent directory, same level as src. As so: https://imgur.com/HGsCYc2

Comment: Try `frame.getClass().getResource("/assets/images/ravens.jpg");` exactly copy/pasted.. 1) This is not a system resource. 2) The first call probably gets the system class loader. 3) Use the leading slash on the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to do this without getting a `NullPointerException` by using a `BufferedImage`. I've tested this and it works. Replace your code with this:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/images/ravens.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {}
frame.setIconImage(img);
```

Comment: Why would this solve the problem (also given it was taken from `getSystemResource`)?

Comment: `When using a relative path, put a slash at the beginning of the path` This is not a file system path. It is a resource name. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: I've changed the answer, it is now correct.  Use a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've stated in your comments, your `assets` directory is at the same level as `src`, so something like

```
/project
    /src
    /assets
```

What you need to do to make this

```
java.net.URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("assets/images/ravens.jpg");
```

work is to have `assets/images/ravens.jpg` be on the classpath.

Eclipse puts anything inside a source folder on the root of the classpath when running your app.

Therefore, create a folder `resources` (or whatever you want to call it), make it a source folder, and put `assets` in it. It should look like

```
/project
    /src
    /resources
        /assets  
            /...
```

Now, `assets` will be at the root of the classpath and you can retrieve it with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon("assets/images/ravens.jpg").getImage());
```